# Page will not echo results with PDO statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My function does not want to load. I am trying to echo out `id`, `name`, and `age`. What am I doing wrong?

```php
<?php

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "testdb";

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

function getManger () {

    global $con;

    $sql= $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM test_tbl");
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->execute();    

    while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) { 

        $id= $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $age - $row['age'];

        echo "<li>$id</li>";
        echo "<li>$name</li>";
        echo "<li>$age</li>";

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: What is `$con`? What is `$age - $row['age'];`? Where do you call `getManger()`?

Comment: I don't think that your function getManger() is executed, at least not in the code you have showed to us...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To outline the errors in your code, and offer a tested and working solution:*

- You're calling the `prepare()` function twice.
- Using the wrong variable for your SELECT.
  ...using `$sql` where it should be `$stmt`
- Not *possibly* calling your `getManger()` function.
- Using a hyphen instead of an equal sign
  `$age - $row['age'];` => `$age = $row['age'];`

**Rewrite:**

```
<?php 
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "testdb";

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

  function getManger($dbh) {

    $stmt= $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM test_tbl");
    $stmt->execute();    

    while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) { 

        $id   = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $age  = $row['age'];

        echo "<li>$id</li>";
        echo "<li>$name</li>";
        echo "<li>$age</li>";
    }
}

// call the function
getManger($dbh);
```

---

***Footnotes***:

It's usually best to pass your DB connection variable inside your function, rather than making it global.

Here are a few articles on Stack about global:

- **https://stackoverflow.com/a/5166527/**
- **https://stackoverflow.com/a/5166276/**

*The choice is yours.*

Comment: Talk about above and beyond

Comment: ty This worked only thing is I have to figure how to get it to another page to be able to select names in a dropdown.

Answer (score 3):

You use

```
global $con;
```

But do not reference it anymore inside the function, instead you reference `$dbh` which is out of function scope as it's nor passed not set to be a global reference,  so options may be:

```
function getManger () {
global $dbh;

$sql= $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM test_tbl");

...
}
```

Or

```
function getManger ($DBCon) {

$sql= $DBCon->prepare("SELECT * FROM test_tbl");
...
}
```

Then call the function:

```
getManager($dbh);
```

This will pass the database connection variable directly into the functions parameters to be used internally. I'd more recommend this over using `global`

Further more. It doesn't seem like you're even calling the function in question based on the code. Are you sure you're doing that?

---

Other typos inside the function may be:

```
$age - $row['age'];
```

Which you're currently telling PHP to subtract `$row['age'];` from an integer stored in `$age`, perhaps you mean:

```
$age = $row['age'];
```

and as pointed by @fred-ii in the comments. You are calling prepare twice, which is unnecessary and could fire an error, depending on your error reporting setup.

```
$sql= $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM test_tbl");
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
```

Should be either 1)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test_tbl";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
```

OR

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM test_tbl");
```

but also a possible typo in the second prepare command?

> $stmt = **$db**->prepare($sql);

Comment: Plus, is using `prepare` twice and not to mention using the wrong variable again `$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);`

Comment: your right I need to call function on the page or on a separate page ty

Comment: @Fred-ii- Still going over the complications in OPS code, got the main problems nailed in the original post, now just time to edit to make it perfect

Comment: I think the OP's well on her way to success ;)